# How to install ROS hydro beta?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I want to install ROS hydro beta same way as Groovy ROS: http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu.

I search in ROS website but i don't found how to install it.
Any idea?
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69433/how-to-install-ros-hydro-beta?/) by [underwater](https://answers.ros.org/users/1303/underwater/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full
```

But you cannot install it as Debian packages of Groovy ROS, don't know what you mean by that. Perhaps you mean the same way as Groovy.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [underwater](https://answers.ros.org/users/1303/underwater/) on 2013-07-28**:
exactly- Is the next following commands are the same way as Groovy?
For example:

1- apt-cache search ros-hydro
2- sudo rosdep init
3- rosdep update
4- echo "source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc